# How can I configure an Azure Function triggered by Service Bus with a custom INameResolver?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-functions-runtime

I want to be able to control the name of the Service Bus Queue or Subscription that my Azure Function reads from at run-time.

With WebJobs (which Azure Functions are based on) you could do this by implementing and configuring a custom `INameResolver`, see: [How to have a configuration based queue name for web job processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860550/how-to-have-a-configuration-based-queue-name-for-web-job-processing)

However, with Azure functions I have no access to `JobHostConfiguration` to wire up this custom resolver.

**Can I still use an `INameResolver`, and if so how?**

Comment: Cross-posted to: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/345

Answer (score 5):

Right now you cannot use a custom `INameResolver` as there is no mechanism for injecting your own services like this into the host. It's being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1579